# How to block HTTP and HTTPS using ufw?

Tags: https, ufw

I have **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** installed, I want to deny **HTTP** and **HTTPS** requests using **ufw**.

I enabled the **ufw** and set firewall rules using these commands ~>

```
sudo ufw deny http
```

and

```
 sudo ufw deny https
```

But When i open a website (http/https)  in a browser (Google Chrome) they works fine, I want to block them.

How can i do that ?

Comment: For very obvious reasons, I have to ask: what are you trying to protect against?  Sites can still use proxies, etc.; if you're trying to just block traffic that'd go outside your network there's a better approach by blacklisting outgoing traffic by default and only allow to internal network IPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are blocking incoming connections. Use

```
sudo ufw deny out 80
sudo ufw deny out 443
```

This will likely also block `apt` updates, so be careful.

Comment: This will also block a *ton* of other things that you probably are trying to protect against as well.

Comment: This also won't protect against http or https served over other ports, which requires very little config in Apache iirc. If you're worried about data leaks, airgap the computer.